# Android OneTime IntentService dies when app is killed

Tags: android, kotlin, intentservice

I need to run a task after 10 seconds, even if the app is closed. I created IntentService:

```
class SomeService: IntentService() {

    override fun onHandleIntent(intent: Intent?) {
        Thread.sleep(10_000)
        somefunction()
    }
}
```

Intent service dies after app dies.
I can't relaunch it with BroadcastReceiver, because its one-time service, which must perform this action after 10 seconds

Comment: Workmanager (https://www.androidauthority.com/schedule-background-tasks-jetpacks-workmanager-874189/) is there to solve your problem.. and intent service will die along with the application .. if you dont want touse workmanager which is recomended then sticky service is there.

Comment: Oh, thanks, I will try it ;) I don't know about Workers.

Comment: its good coz you are  going to learn it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting Android Developer Guide

> IntentService is subject to all the background execution limits
>   imposed with Android 8.0 (API level 26)

You can read more about the restrictions here https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background

Some solutions you can try are

1)Have a foreground service (Attach a notification to the service)

In Java, the way I do is I have two utility methods created

```
public static void startNotificationAlongWithForegroundService(Service service,String CHANNEL_ID_FOREGROUND,String CHANNEL_NAME_FOREGROUND, String title, String body, Integer notification_id) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(service, CHANNEL_ID_FOREGROUND)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(body)
                .setOngoing(true)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setProgress(100, 0, true);

        NotificationManager mNotificationManager =  (NotificationManager) service.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        NotificationChannel channel =  mNotificationManager.getNotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID_FOREGROUND);

        if(channel==null) {
            channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID_FOREGROUND,CHANNEL_NAME_FOREGROUND, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_NONE);
            channel.setShowBadge(false);

            if (mNotificationManager != null) {
                    mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
            }

        }
        service.startForeground(notification_id, builder.build());
    }
}

public static void destroyForegroundService(Service context) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        context.stopForeground(true);
    }
}
```

And in your service

```
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

    Utils.startNotificationAlongWithForegroundService(this,"channel_id","channelname","title","body",123);
    //your work
    Utils.destroyForegroundService(this);
}
```

2)Use JobService/Workmanager

I will update the answer with the examples on this shortly if you are not comfortable with using Job services/WorkManager.

Comment: Thanks, JobService helped me